# Looping through %1 as a directory in batch?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, input

I've searched the web for answers but can't seem to find an answer. I want the user to provide a directory and to be able to loop through it. I'm able to loop through the current directory like so:

```
@Echo off
for /r %%f in (*.*) do (
    echo    %%f
)
```

But then when I try to do the same by looping through %1, I can't get the result I'm looking for. What am I doing wrong? Here's where I'm at in the batch file:

```
@Echo off

if exist %1 (
    for /r %%f in (%1) do (
        echo    %%f
    )

) else (
    echo "That directory does not exist."
)
```

I've tried using `/D` but all that did was echo the directory I provided like this:

```
FileCount C:\Users\Me\Desktop
> C:\Users\Me\Desktop
```

**Edit:** My goal for this program is to eventually count the number of files within the given directory. I expect the directory to be provided as it's absolute path and I'll be executing this file through cmd. Here's an example of the input I'm expecting.

```
FileCount C:\Users\Me\Desktop
```

And the desired output would be something like:

```
> Hello world.txt
> Cat.png
> There are 2 files within this directory.
```

*Side-note: I don't want to filter out the output of the dir command, I want to do this with a for loop.*

Comment: Could you please provide more information regarding the task. What are you expecting the input to be, a directory name only, an absolute path, or a relative path. How is the input argument being provided, Command Prompt, or Windows Explorer, or via another running executable file? There are many ways of performing tasks in a batch file, but a focused, robust and/or efficient solution would be much simpler, armed with that information. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65766270/edit) to provide that information, do not post it as a comment!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Do you want it to recurs below the specified directory? And did you search for [how to count files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch%5Dcount+files+in+directory)?

Comment: If you're executing it through command, does that mean that you'll be providing it like this: `Call "C:\Users\SuperUser42\MyScript.cmd" "C:\Users\SuperUser42\Documents"`, `MyScript C:\Users\SuperUser42\Documents`, or something else. Please remember, the less information you provide, the less chance you have of receiving a properly focused solution. Also, have you opened a Command Prompt window, entered `for /?` and read the usage information. Had you done so, you'd have seen `/D` and should have noticed that it expects a glob, not a string.

Comment: I'd prefer if it didn't recurse below the specified directory and yes I've searched for that but couldn't find anything that including how to go about looping through %1 without using the dir command.

Comment: The problem with using globs (* and ?) to search for things, is they only work on directory entry names, which can be files or directories. Not all files are created using the name.ext convention and some directories have extensions (dir.ext). The dir command is the simplest and also runs faster than iterating over files. Why do you insist on bucking the common sense of tens of thousands of developers with a combined millions of years more experience than you have?

Comment: I agree with @jwdonahue, the `dir` command, is also the correct command to list your files and count them too, _(if you use `dir` at the Command Prompt, you'll clearly see the names of the files and the file count in the output. As your end goal is to retrieve that information, it would seem more efficient to use it at the outset)_. Also `for`, `for /d`, and `for /r` do not get all files and/or directories, whereas `dir` provides options to do so!

Comment: If you didn't want it to recurse why did you chose to use the `/R` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help everybody, I've found the solution to the problem and it was very simple. All I needed to do was loop through `%1\*.*` instead of `%1` itself.

```
@Echo off

if exist %1 (
    for %%f in (%1\*.*) do (
        echo    %%f
    )

) else (
    echo "That directory does not exist."
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you asked for, plus the optional recurs feature. Note that this will miss hidden files and directories.

```
@setlocal EnableExtensions
@prompt=$G

@set _Error_Success=0
@set _Error_PathNotFound=3

@if "%~1" equ "/?" goto :Usage
@if "%~1" equ "" goto :Usage
@if "%~1" equ "/r" (@set _recurs=/r & @set _root=%~2) else (@set _root=%~1)
@if not exist "%_root%" goto :Oops

@set count=0

@pushd "%_root%"
@for %_recurs% %%f in (*) do @call :Counter "%%f"
@popd

@echo There are %count% entries within this directory.
@exit /b %_Error_Success%

:Counter
@set /a count+=1
@echo %~1
@exit /b %_Error_Success%

:Oops
@echo "That directory does not exist."
@exit /b %_Error_PathNotFound%

:Usage
@echo Usage: FileCount [/r] path
```

And this uses the dir command, without resorting to invoking findstr:

```
@setlocal EnableExtensions
@prompt=$G

@set _Error_Success=0
@set _Error_PathNotFound=3
@set _Error_InvalidParameter=87

@set _attributes=
@set _recurs=
@set _count=0

@if "%~1" equ "/?" @goto :Usage & @exit
@if "%~1" equ "" goto :Usage

@set _root=%~1
@if not exist "%_root%" goto :Oops

@shift

@pushd "%_root%"
for /f %%G in ('dir /B /A-d %1 %2 %_root%') do @call :Counter "%%G"
@popd

@echo There are %_count% entries within this directory.
@exit /b %_Error_Success%

:Counter
@set /a _count+=1
@echo %~1
@exit /b %_Error_Success%

:HandleOptions

:Oops
@echo "That directory does not exist."
@exit /b %_Error_PathNotFound%

:Usage
@echo Usage: FileCount [/A<Attributes>] [/S] rootPath
@echo   Where <Attributes> corresponds to 'dir /A' optiions (see 'help dir')
@echo   and /S will cause recursion into subdirectories of rootPath.
```

Answer (score 0):

This example, uses a `for` loop, and does not use the `dir` command, as per your inexplicable request, but it does use `xcopy` to list and count the files within it instead:

```batch-file
@For %%G In ("%~1") Do @If "%%~aG" Lss "d" (If "%%~aG" GEq "-" (
        Echo Error: File argument given, expected a directory.
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
        Exit /B 1) Else (
        Echo Error: Invalid argument, directory path expected.
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
        Exit /B 1)
) Else Echo File content of "%~1":& For /F Delims^= %%H In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%~1" : /HIL') Do @Echo %%~nxH
@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T -1 & Exit /B 0
```

---

If you want it to recurse the input directory, then I'd suggest this very small modification:

```batch-file
@For %%G In ("%~1") Do @If "%%~aG" Lss "d" (If "%%~aG" GEq "-" (
        Echo Error: File argument given, expected a directory.
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
        Exit /B 1) Else (
        Echo Error: Invalid argument, directory path expected.
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
        Exit /B 1)
) Else Echo File content of "%~1":& For /F Delims^= %%H In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%~1" : /HILS') Do @Echo %%H
@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T -1 & Exit /B 0
```

Or with a little more work, outputting relative paths instead:

```batch-file
@For %%G In ("%~1") Do @If "%%~aG" Lss "d" (If "%%~aG" GEq "-" (
        Echo Error: File argument given, expected a directory.
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
        Exit /B 1) Else (
        Echo Error: Invalid argument, directory path expected.
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
        Exit /B 1)
) Else Echo File content of "%~1":& For /F Delims^= %%H In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%~1" : /HILS') Do @(
        Set "}=%%H" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        For %%I In ("!}:*%~1=.!") Do @EndLocal & Echo %%~I)
@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T -1 & Exit /B 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem Put it into a folder that is in ENV PATH variable.
rem So, you can call it from wherever you want.
if not "%~1"=="" (
    if exist "%~dpn1" (
        set /a "filecount=0"
        for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('dir /b "%~dpn1"') do (
          echo    %%f
          set /a "filecount+=1"
        )
        echo:
        echo In "%~dpn1" found !filecount! file^(s^).

    ) else (
        echo:
        echo [ERROR] Invalid input. Please specify:
        echo    1. A full path.
        echo    2. A folder in cwd.
        echo:
        echo If input is empty, current working directory (cwd)
        echo will be considered.
        exit /b 1
    )
) else (
    
    set /a "filecount=0"
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('dir /b "%~dp0"') do (
      echo    %%f
      set /a "filecount+=1"
    )
    echo:
    echo In "%~dp0" found !filecount! file^(s^).

)


endlocal
```

If you want it recursive call it as `progname.bat /r [foldname]`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem Put it into a folder that is in ENV PATH variable.
rem So, you can call it from wherever you want.

if "%1"=="/r" shift

if not "%1"=="" (
    if exist "%~dpn1" (


        set /a "filecount=0"
        set /a "totalcount=0"
        set "oldroot=%~dpn1"

        for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s "!cd!"') do (

            if not "%%~dpf"=="!oldroot!" (
                echo:
                echo In "!oldroot!" found !filecount! file^(s^).
                echo:
                set /a "filecount=0"
                set "oldroot=%%~dpf"
            )
            echo  ---   %%f
            set /a "filecount+=1"
            set /a "totalcount+=1"
        )
        echo:
        echo In "%~dpn1" found !totalcount! file^(s^).

    ) else (
        echo:
        echo [ERROR] Invalid input. Please specify:
        echo    1. A full path.
        echo    2. A folder in cwd.
        echo:
        echo If input is empty, current working directory (cwd)
        echo will be considered.
        exit /b 1
    )
) else (
    
    set /a "filecount=0"
    set /a "totalcount=0"
    set "oldroot=!cd!"

    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s "!cd!"') do (

        if not "%%~dpf"=="!oldroot!" (
            echo:
            echo In "!oldroot!" found !filecount! file^(s^).
            echo:
            set /a "filecount=0"
            set "oldroot=%%~dpf"
        )
        echo  ---   %%f
        set /a "filecount+=1"
        set /a "totalcount+=1"
    )
    echo:
    echo In "%~dp0" found !totalcount! file^(s^).

)


endlocal
```

Try it and see if it is what you expected.